# bootstrap 5 carousel not working in all browser - not same layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Here is an example of a carousel as per BS5 doc.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Fair Trade Tourism</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- STYLES : CSS & FONTS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
    button { border:0px !important;}
    .carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next { background-color: transparent !important; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<!-- CAROUSEL - (TITLE - SUMMARY) -->
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>

    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="8000">
            <img src="/public/images/banners/FTT_104117.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="8000">
            <img src="/public/images/banners/FTT_100607.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="8000">
            <img src="/public/images/banners/FTT_104510.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>


<script src="/public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The live test is http://fairtradetourism.org/test/test1

The carousel is working on Firefox and Safari on mac but not working on Chrome on mac.  I don't know about the other browsers.  Am I missing something?

Also how can I get rid off the faded overlay over the navigation icon inclusing the border.

EDIT: I managed to fix the layout issues (adding some css and changing the class of the control buttons) but the carousel still does not slide, not even when clicking on the button!

Comment: For me it works on Firefox on Windows, Google Chrome in Windows, Microsoft Edge in Windows. And slide works well, Just wait until page completely load (Because I noticed your project is slow as well).

Comment: Thank you @KevinM.Mansour... good to know.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? I get this one on Edge 18 (legacy), and it's caused by an unsupported param expansion: SCRIPT1028